# how to make user accounts and store separate data for each of them using python pyrebase?

Tags: python, python-3.x, firebase, pyrebase

I am making a Tkinter/flask app that stores user's data on a local `SQLite` database.

But now I want to store every user's data on `firebase` but I don't know how to store/retrieve data separately for every single user using `pyrebase`.

if this is not possible to achieve by `pyrebase` then please suggest any other package that I can use. And also give an example code for that package.

Answer (score 0):

pyrabse is good library to store the data. It can connect firestore easily. it is typically NoSQL Database. but if you want more flexibility then use another library. try [google cloud store](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-firestore/)

Comment: the thing is, I want to store different data for the different user but I don't know how can I achieve that